# Can babel-plugin-relay work with the typescript compiler?

Tags: typescript, ts-jest, relayjs

Relay and typescript work well together, when compiled with Babel. The babel-plugin-relay can be used to transform the `graphql` tagged template. However I'm using ts-auto-mock in the unittests, which requires the actual typescript compiler (Babel does not work). But to unittest Fragments I need the `graphql` keyword, which requires the babel-plugin-relay. Is there any way to get the babel-plugin-relay to work with the typescript compiler?